# Checking/Unchecking Radio Button States

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

I am working on an application in which I have a customized list view. This list view contains  1 `CheckBox`, 1 `RadioButton` and 1 `TextBox`. I can't use Radio Group as I have only one RadioButton. I am having difficulties in maintaining the state of that only Radio Button. What I want is:

**From all the entries in a list, select only one row's Radio Button.**

which means, If I select a RadioButton from some other row in the List the first one should be unchecked and the newer one must be checked and so on.

Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance...:-)

Comment: Set a Tag(tag=row number) for Each Radio Button and Change their States According to Tag number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i m Not aware of Android but Here is what i m Doing for iPhone Apps. Hope This will work For android Too.

Set a `Tag` (`tag=row` number) for Each Radio Button and Change their States According to Tag number.